# need details regarding Azure monitoring

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-performancecounters

[image]we have one question we have one vm hosted in azure do not have Insight enable.

and while creation we do not enable log and diagnostic are off.so question is why we are able to see this

can anyone tell from where the matrix are coming as attach

monitoring is coming from where

Thanks

DJM

Answer (score 2):

You will still need Azure monitor, there is **NO** service which provides specific metrics as you mentioned above.

Comment: Hi,i have attach the image my question is from where it is coming even though i have disable the management and diagnostic tools in vm

Comment: i dont see any image in the question